# Poor performance when adding large number of elements to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have produced a table but I am using `<div>`s instead of `<tr>`s and `<td>`s. here is an example:

```
<div class="tbl tbl1">
    <div class="thead">
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td colTitle" style="width: 120px"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="td colLink" style="width: 190px"><span>Link</span></div>
            <div class="td colSize numeric" style="width: 75px"><span>Size(MB)</span></div>
            <div class="td colUploadDate" style="width: 75px"><span>UploadDate</span></div>
            <div class="td colOpen" style="width: 50px; max-width: 50px;"><span>Show</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td colTitle">
                <input type="text" class="Filter" />
            </div>
            <div class="td colLink">
                <input type="text" class="Filter" />
            </div>
            <div class="td colSize">
                <input type="text" class="Filter" />
            </div>
            <div class="td colUploadDate">
                <input type="text" class="Filter" />
            </div>
            <div class="td colOpen">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tbody">
    </div>
</div>
```

I will fill `tbody` with an ajax function. After getting all data from the database, I store it into an array in client-side. I use below codes to fill my table using array `arr`. But when I have a large number of rows it takes a lot of time to display rows in my table.

```
var res = "";
arr.forEach(function (row) {
    res += "<div class='tr' idattachment='" + row["IdAttachment"] + "' >" +
            "<div class='td colTitle'>" + row["Title"] + "</div>" +
            "<div class='td colLink'>" + row["Name"] + "</div>" +
            "<div class='td colSize'>" + (row["Size"] / (1024 * 1024)).toFixed(2) + "</div>" +
            "<div class='td colUploadDate'>" + row["UploadDate"] + "</div>" +
            "<div class='td colOpen'><a class='link' href='uploads/" + row["Name"] + "'>Open</a></div>" +
            "</div>";
});
$(".tbody").html(res);
```

Is there any more efficient way to load data into table?

Comment: You should consider using a templating engine and/or pagination.

Comment: I don't want to use the paging option.

Comment: How about doing that "row by row" with a small delay inbetween? That way it takes longer to load but it doesnt freeze.

Comment: Given that you are building all your html into a single string and only doing one append, if that is taking a "long time" to display, that is reflective of the amount of data you are trying to display

Comment: If you really need to show a huge table, at first, drop jQuery, and use [HTMLTable Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement), it is optimized to handle tables. Avoid adding classes or ids, or actually any attributes to the table elements. Also avoid heavy styling, use `colgroup`/`col` elements and/or stylesheet (`nth-child` selectors) to style the elements. You can test whether a documentFragment is faster to append rows and cells than appending them directly on the page, or try to append to a `display:none` table, which you can show after it's ready.

Comment: How many rows are we talking here?

Comment: @epascarello between 2000  and 10000

Comment: The foreach on its own building the string is going to be slow with 10,000 items. Than just the browser rendering that much is going to be slow. You probably will have to chunk and render....

Answer (score 1):

Use virtual rendering to only render the rows that are actually in view.

Example with [Clusterize.js](https://clusterize.js.org/):

```js
var rows = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  rows.push('<tr><td>Row ' + i + '</td></tr>');
}

var clusterize = new Clusterize({
  rows: rows,
  scrollId: 'scrollArea',
  contentId: 'tbody'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clusterize.js/0.18.0/clusterize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clusterize.js/0.18.0/clusterize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="clusterize-scroll" id="scrollArea">
  <table>
      <thead class="thead">
          <tr class="tr">
              <td>
                <span>Title</span>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tbody" class="clusterize-content">
        <tr class="clusterize-no-data">
          <td>Loading data…</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>   
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to do a performance analysis. I will go step by step so you can try and do the same if you like the pattern. Keep in mind some times this analysis will say there is nothing obvious you can do.

## Performance Goals

When ever you are trying to archive a level performance the first question should be what are we trying to do.

The normal scale is as follows.

- < 16ms for animations
- < 100ms for immediate reactions
- 100-300ms Slight perceptible delay
- 300-1000ms A task being done.
- > 1s loss of Focus.
- > 10s Frustration and abandons task

It seems you are doing a task so <= 1s is the Goal.

When caring about these Goal follow the data.

## JS

You are using forEach seems to be the best option.
https://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/75

String Plus vs template literal, does not seem to matter.
https://jsperf.com/template-literal-vs-string-plus/7

Dot Notation vs Square Bracket Notation, does not seem to matter.
https://jsperf.com/dot-notation-vs-square-bracket-notation/5

#### JS Conclusion

The data supports your Javascript is as optimized as it can be.

## CSS

CSS not provided.

#### CSS Conclusion

Inconclusive

## Rendering

jQuery append vs html vs innerHTML

https://jsperf.com/jquery-append-vs-html-list-performance/24

It seems using innerHTML would be a better choice.

#### Rendering Conclusion

Change .html to innerHTML

## Perception

When I render this code without CSS in a as you did not provide it. I start hitting 1s render times when I render 10,000 items.

You can paginate the rendering but if you do this you will need to load chunks that take < 16ms to render. Even if you think you don't have animation scrolling is an animation.

When you do your testing on low end device and get how many items can be rendered under 1 second do the following. I'm using 10k as I hit 1s on my device. 10,000 / 1000 * 15 This will give you the number of items you can load in 1s without disrupting animation.

Add a Spinner or something that shows work is being done. So the user thinks in terms of something is working which gains time from < 100ms to 300-1000ms.

#### Perception Conclusion

Paginate

Add Spinner or show work is being done.

That's all I got. Good Luck.

Answer (score -1):

Give the browser some breathing space while loading.

```
var nextRow = 0;
var handler;


//Process a row in every 250ms
var handler = setInterval(function() {

   //Select next row
   var row =arr[nextRow];

   var res= "<div class='tr' idattachment='" + row["IdAttachment"] + "' >" +
            "<div class='td colTitle'>" + row["Title"] + "</div>" +
            "<div class='td colLink'>" + row["Name"] + "</div>" +
            "<div class='td colSize'>" + (row["Size"] / (1024 * 1024)).toFixed(2) + "</div>" +
            "<div class='td colUploadDate'>" + row["UploadDate"] + "</div>" +
            "<div class='td colOpen'><a class='link' href='uploads/" + row["Name"] + "'>Open</a></div>" +
            "</div>";

   //Append
   $(".tbody").appendChild(res);

   //Move on
   nextRow++;

   //Exit at the end
   if (arr.length === nextRow)
      clearInterval(handler);

}, 250);
```

This will keep adding your data to the table until the end.

Also remember, string concatenation is expensive. You could even try the `appendChild` method without the interval.

Comment: This will allow some breathing room but will cause the browser to do extra DOM and CSS layout work which could actually be slower. The building of the table should happen without your setInterval but with the appendChild after the last row is added.

Comment: The browser will not freeze. The overall operation will be lot smoother than OPs method.

Comment: It's a good idea to show each row once it's ready. but it doesn't help with the speed problem.

Comment: I didn't say the browser will freeze. The browser may even feel like it is running smoothly but the browser will ultimately work harder because of re-rendering.

Comment: Browsers are for working harder :). OP want to make it faster and smoother. He can close the browser if he feel the poor thing is tired. ;)

Comment: Also.. the OPs practice is unconventional. You never load a large amount of data at once like this (10s of MBs??) So, if he really don't like pagination too, the best is to start showing data soon as possible.

Comment: True, I updated my answer using your method but instead of setInterval, I thing requestAnimationFrame is a better option. The 3rd answer added saying only render what is visible is also a great answer, but as you said, not wanting to use pagination, I can only imagine not wanting to handle render visible :)